# What does "$s-$" mean in $F(s_n)\uparrow F(s-)\le F(s)$

Tags: notation

In the case at hand $F$ is the distribution function for a random variable and $s_n \uparrow s$, and so $F(s_n)\uparrow F(s)$ but what about this $F(s-)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just a guess, but if the distribution has a discrete "density" at $s$, this might be shorthand for the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $s$ from below.  More context would be helpful to understand your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the notation to show the limit from under : $$F(s-) = \lim\limits_{\begin{array}{l} t\to s\\t < s\end{array}} F(t)$$

Related, you could have a look at what "[càdlàg](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)" (in french : continue à droite, limite à gauche) which means continuous on the right and limit on the left.